# Ruby irbrc_history system-wide. How to make it local?

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, irb

I installed ruby on Ubuntu for system-wide use.  The `.irbrc_history` file is created in a system directory rather than the user's home directory. This causes an access error when the file is owned by someone else. Here's the error besides a bunch more that I think is irrelevant:

```
irb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:75:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/.irbrc_history (Errno::EACCES)
```

Deleting the history file resolves the error.

I tried adding environment variables and history initialization code to what I think is the system `.irbrc` file, but to no avail.

What is the sequence of initialization files being executed that impact this history file?  How can I change the location of the history file?

Comment: Have you found a fix yet? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

Create, or edit your ~/.irbrc file to include:

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 200
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history"
```

Source: [How To Persist Rails or IRB Console Command History After Exit](https://jdc.io/how-to-persist-rails-or-irb-console-command-history-after-exit)

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to use RVM?

rvm 1.29.3 (current stable) has a bug where IRB history gets saved in the `RUBY_HOME` instead of `HOME`.

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4158

Here's a fix:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 2.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the file in your home directory: `touch ~/.irbrc_history`.

Or copy it from the system path to your home directory: `cp /path/of/system/.irbrc_history ~/.irbrc_history`

Note that you should change `/path/of/system/` to whatever you have on your system.

Once the file is in your home directory (given by `~`) then it will run when your user runs `irb`

Comment: For some reason this doesn't quite fix it, nor does removing the system-wide one. Still get the same error using newer versions of RVM.